# How to add oversampling/undersampling procedure in scikit's Pipeline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I would like to add oversampling procedure, like [SMOTE oversampling](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/jair/pub/volume16/chawla02a-html/chawla2002.html), to scikit's [Pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html). But the [transformers](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.TransformerMixin.html#sklearn.base.TransformerMixin) only supports `fit` and `transform` method, and do not provide a way to increase the number of samples and targets.

One possible way to do this is to break the pipeline to two separate pipelines connected by SMOTE sampling.

Is there any better solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our current `Pipeline` does not support changing the number of samples between steps as the `Transformer.transform` method does not return the `y` argument that would need to also be resampled. This is a know limitation of the current design. It might be fixed in a future version but we have not started to work on that yet.

Comment: Since class imbalance problem is very common, there should be a oversampling/undersampling procedure in scikit's library.

Comment: You can adjust the weights of the samples to try and overcome this. Or you can resample your data beforehand.